# Can I convert a defaultdict or dict to an ordereddict in Python?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta, defaultdict

I am trying to parse a fasta file and then I want to create another file which will contain all possible 100th sequence of ATGCN of the fasta file.

For example：

```
chr1_1-100:ATGC.....GC  
chr1_2-101:ATGC.....GC  
chr1_3-102:ATGC.....GC  
......................  
chr22_1-100:ATGC....cG  
chr22_2-101:ATGC....cG  
......................
```

I did it with the following code:

```
    from Bio import SeqIO
    from Bio.Seq import Seq
    from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
    records = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(open(i1), 'fasta'))
    with open(out, 'w') as f:
       for key in records:
     long_seq_record = records[key]
     long_seq = long_seq_record.seq
     length=len(long_seq)
     alphabet = long_seq.alphabet
     for i in range(0, length-99):  
         short_seq = str(long_seq)[i:i+100]
         text="@"+key+"_"+str(i)+"-"+str(i+100)+":"+"\n"+short_seq+"\n"+"+"+"\n"+"IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII\n"
     f.write(text)
```

The problem is that the written file is not ordered.means it can contain `chr10` first then `chr2`.

The problem is there because the parsing is done using `dict(` e.g., `SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(open(i1), 'fasta'))`.

So, Can I convert the dict into an ordered dict so that my files become ordered? or is there any other way to get the solution?

Comment: you can use the `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module or like you knew this already and want a specific solution to ur issue?

Comment: Why create a dict at all? It seems like `SeqIO.parse` already does everything you actually need here.

Comment: the seqIO.to_dict() returns a dict not an ordered dict ,thats why , when I am trying to retrieve each record it is not ordered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother making any sort of dict at all. You don't need the properties a dict gives you, and you need the information the dict conversion loses. The record iterator from `SeqIO.parse` already gives you what you need:

```
with open(i1) as infile, open(out, 'w') as f:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(infile, 'fasta'):
        # Do what you were going to do with the record.
```

If you need the information that was in the dict key, that's `record.id`.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't do what u suggested.I need each 100th sequence of every key in dict.If I use your code I am getting error:File "slidedfa.py", line 14
    with open(i1) as infile, open(out, 'w') as f:
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @SurachitSarkar: If you can update to Python 2.7, do so. Otherwise, you'll need to use two separate `with` statements.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I convert a defaultdict or dict to an ordereddict in Python?

Yes, you can convert it `OrderedDict(any_dict)` and if you need to order the keys, you can sort them before creating the `OrderedDict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = {'c':'c', 'b':'b', 'a':'a'}
>>> o = OrderedDict((key, d[key]) for key in sorted(d))
>>> o.items()[0]
('a', 'a')
>>> o.items()[1]
('b', 'b')
>>> o.items()[2]
('c', 'c')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly identified the cause of the problem: the `to_dict` method returns a dict, meaning that order has been lost. Since that point, there is no way to recover the order.

More, you do not really use the dict, because you process everything sequentially, so you could just iterate:

```
for record in SeqIO.parse(open(i1), 'fasta')) :
    key = record.id
    long_seq = record.seq
    ...
```